# Qt json parser return parse error

Tags: qt, json

I try to parse json string using this method:

```
QString ourJSONData = QString('{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.1"}');
QString response = QString("[") + QString(ourJSONData) + QString("]");

QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptValue sc = engine.evaluate(response);

ui->label->setText(sc.toString());
```

But label return

> SyntaxError: Parse error

I using Qt 4.7.4

What i do wrong? Thanks.

**UPD:**

Sorry, problem was in that string:

> QString ourJSONData = QString('{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.1"}');

need change to:

> QString ourJSONData = QString("{\"couchdb\":\"Welcome\",\"version\":\"1.0.1\"}");

P.S. this method i found at http://blog.siegerstein.com/archives/134

Comment: You should use a real JSON parser to handle JSON instead of a JavaScript engine's `eval` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built your code in QtCreator in got a very helpful error message:

> character constant too long for its type

It's because your `ourJSONData` variable is initialised with a text in single quotes, which is for single characters.

This will correct that initialisation. (I put a `\` before each double-quote, and then changed the single-quotes to double):

```
QString ourJSONData = QString("{\"couchdb\":\"Welcome\",\"version\":\"1.0.1\"}");
```